# Google apps script Gmail oldest thread date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I write script for find first written thread in Gmail. How using google apps script get oldest thread date in inbox?

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; 
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message 
Logger.log(message.getDate()); // Log date and time of the message
```

Comment: Welcome to stack we are not a coding service.  Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution

Comment: this code 
`var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
Logger.log(message.getDate()); // Log date and time of the message` 
gives first message date, but I need last date of a thread or message in inbox

Comment: So don't read just the first message in the array of messages. Look at all of the messages in the thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access date/time of emails using appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948541/how-to-access-date-time-of-emails-using-appscript)

Comment: I understand this, and first thread date i find by using script in question, but how get last thread date?

Comment: Check message date for more than one thread, to compare threads. Probably this will be faster if you perform searches based on dates and programmatically change the date span until there are no messages.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: You can use the below snippet.

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
Logger.log(message.getDate()); // Log date and time of the message
```

Please refer the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate()).

Comment: I need get date of first message in gmail inbox, when i sort message from last to new i see this message date in last message, and i dont know how to get this date by using google script

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate(). PLease see the updated answer

Comment: i use your script in log was #Thu Jan 10 14:36:56 GMT+02:00 2019# but this is my newest message. I want to find date my oldest message (2017) year

Comment: var threads = GmailApp.search('startDate: urDate'); Use this to get the threads specifying the date. and get the message from the thread.getMessages[0];

Comment: i want to get date of last message in last thread!! I dont need to get message by typing date in  'urDate'